# Probability of second random number is larger than the first one?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, natural-numbers

Imagine n1 is the first random number and n2 is the second one, both between A and B and both are natural.
What is the probability that n2 is greater than n1?

What if there is another n3 random number between A and B, then what is the probability that n3 > n2 > n1 ?

Is there any general formula for adding whatever numbers in a row?

Comment: This will depend on the distribution from which the random numbers are chosen. Do you mean that the numbers are chosen from a discrete uniform distribution? Also, you should add your attempts so far.

Comment: Are you sampling uniformly? If so, you may wish to note via symmetry that $$\mathbb{P}(n_1>n_2)=\mathbb{P}(n_1<n_2)$$ $$\mathbb{P}(n_1>n_2)+\mathbb{P}(n_1<n_2)+\mathbb{P}(n_1=n_2)=1$$ Therefore, $$\mathbb{P}(n_2>n_1)=\frac{1-\mathbb{P}(n_1=n_2)}{2}$$ You can apply an similar argument using symmetry to establish a formula for $$\mathbb{P}(n_k>n_{k-1}>\dots >n_1)$$

Comment: @MatthewH. That works even for non-uniform sampling (assuming independence which was not explicitly stated in the question).

Comment: @Momo very useful information! Thank you.

Comment: @Matthew H. Thank you. Very useful.